# How to create a list that have a sub list for each item?

Tags: android, list

I want to have a list that has some item that they work like a button, when click one of the item in that list show some sub list of each item and those sub list should be clickable.
like these pics: [a list](http://uploadboy.com/i9x7n2jad3oe.html),  [after clicking on item of list](http://uploadboy.com/39ykw80uiyui.html)

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any thing to help me...

Comment: you need to use expandable listview http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post pictures somewhere else than a file uploader..

Anyways it sounds like you want an `ExpandableListView`, which is basically a 2 level `ListView`.

There are many examples on the web for that, you should google first :)
.